# Do audiofiles contain digital footprint which enables to trace back to the PC where the audiofile got downloaded and edited?

Tags: audio, metadata, digital-signature

I'm using windows10 os on my pc. so i downloaded few audio files from a website which needs my email to login. My first question is - how to see if those audiofiles contains my email which i used to login that site?
now after downloading those audiofiles to my pc, i edited them with audacity and during saving those edited files i completely kept blank in meta data section. my 2nd question is- will those edited audiofiles have any digital footprint which can b used to traceback to my pc? if so how can i see if there's any digital footprint at all in those files and how to remove those footprints? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If done properly, you cannot hear an [*audio watermark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_watermark). It also cannot be removed, at least not using trivial methods like compressing using a different codec.

You can detect whether tracks are personalized for your account by comparing them against tracks downloaded using a different account. Make sure to compare audio data and metadata separately.

You cannot reliably detect a general watermark (which only says “downloaded from example.com”) except maybe if you can procure the same track from a different source.

Comment: i meant is there any way to check if any personal information or any information about my pc got atached to those files which can be used to trace back to my pc or me? and if those informations got attached to those files how do i remove those informations from those files?

Comment: You can't and you don't. That's kind of the point.